# why would overflow tube fill with water after flushing

Tags: toilet

After flushing while thank is filling the overflow tube fills up with water coming from the refill tube. I know it's not supposed to do that. What could cause this? Should i change the flush valve?

Comment: The diagram in the answer below shows a roller clamp on the hose going to the overflow tube. The purpose of this must be to regulate the flow of water into the overflow tube. If this flow would be too high it could conceivable cause the over flow tube to fill up, but this seems like an unlikely explanation to me. i looked in the tank in one toilet in our house and it does not have a roller clamp on this hose. This  overflow tube does not fill up on flushing.

Comment: Hi! You have a couple of unregistered accounts. Please [register](/help/why-register) one of them, then [merge them](/help/merging-accounts) together, which will allow you to [edit](/help/privileges/create-posts) and [comment on](/help/privileges/comment) any of your posts. Thanks, and welcome to the site!

Answer (score 1):

It is normal for the refill tube to put water into the overflow pipe. It fills the bowl with new water.

The tank is filled by water coming out of the fill valve near the bottom of the tank.

It is not normal for the overflow tube to *fill up* with water. If it is filling with water, it is clogged. Run a wire or fish line or zip tie down the overflow tube to try to dislodge whatever is clogging it.

[image]

Comment: By clogged I assume you mean the hole at the bottom of the overflow tube that goes under the flap. That is not clogged or maybe it is clogged in the whole under the flap that drains into bowl. It fills and overflow while the tank if filling as as soon as tank is filled it drains...

Comment: @Lilypad Without flushing, while the tank is full and not running, pour water directly into the overflow pipe. Does the overflow pipe fill up with water? If you wait five minutes, has the overflow pipe at least partially drained?